# my img in child component was not change from passing new state by parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

im was the beginner at js this is my app.js and im was make tree component that can choose jpg file to show on my pic component
im have tried to use state and callbackfunction so i use ant-designe for my tree and picture component
above is my main app component
#sorry for my bad english
#thank you

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Tree from './Treeapp';
import Pic from './submitapp';
import './App.css';
//window.a="/google landmark/test/0/0/0/00084cdf8f600d00.jpg";
class App extends Component { 
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        path:" "
      }
    }
    changestate=(answer)=>{
      this.setState({answer: answer})
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
          </header>
          <p className="App-intro">
                <Pic path={this.state.path}/>
                <Tree nextstate={this.changestate.bind(this)}/>
          </p>
        </div>
      )
  }
}

export default App
```

my tree component

```
import { Tree } from 'antd';
import React  from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
const { DirectoryTree } = Tree;
const treeData = [
  {
    title : 'index',
    key : '/index',
    children : []
  },
  {
    title : 'test',
    key : '/test',
    children : []
  },
  {
    title : 'train',
    key : '/train',
    children : []
  }  
]
const makeTree=(item,add)=>{
  const pos = item.substring(8,11)
  const head = treeData[1];
  let children = head.children;
  if(!children.find(x=> x.title === pos[0])){
    children.push(
      {
        title : pos[0],
        key : head.key + '/' + pos[0],
        children : [],
    [enter image description here][1]  }
    )
  };
  children = children.find(x=> x.title === pos[0]).children;
  if(!children.find(x=> x.title === pos[1])){
    children.push(
      {
        title : pos[1],
        key : head.key + '/' + pos[0] + '/' + pos[1],
        children : [],
      }
    )
  }
  children = children.find(x=> x.title === pos[1]).children;
  if(!children.find(x=> x.title === pos[2])){
    children.push(
      {
        title : pos[2],
        key : head.key + '/' + pos[0] + '/' + pos[1] + '/' + pos[2],
        children : [],

      }
    )
  }
  children = children.find(x=> x.title === pos[2]).children
  children.push
  (
    {
      title : item.substring(8,item.length),
      key : head.key + '/' + pos[0] + '/' + pos[1] + '/' + pos[2]+ '/' +item.substring(8,item.length),
      isLeaf : true
    }
  );
}
let r = require.context('/project/public/google landmark/test',true);
r.keys().map(item=>makeTree(item,r(item)))
//let u = require.context('/public/google landmark/train',true);
//u.keys().map(item=>makeTree(item,u(item)))
//let v = require.context('/public/google landmark/index',true);
//v.keys().map(item=>makeTree(item,v(item)))
class Demo extends React.Component {
  
  onSelect=(key)=>{
    let answer="/google landmark"+key;
    //console.log(answer);
    this.props.nextstate(answer);
  };
  onExpand(){
    //console.log('Trigger Expand');
  };
  render(){
    return (
        <DirectoryTree
          multiple
          defaultExpandParent
          onSelect={this.onSelect}
          onExpand={this.onExpand}
          treeData={treeData}
        />

    )
  }
};
export default Demo;
```

my pic component that have problem

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'antd';
class ImageDemo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      path: this.props.path // default image.
    }
  }
  render(){
        return (
            <Image
            width={200}
            height={200}
            src={this.state.path}
            />
        )
        
    }
}

export default ImageDemo;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pic component try to use prop instead of state

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'antd';
export default function ImageDemo({path}){
  return (
            <Image
            width={200}
            height={200}
            src={path}
            />
        )
}
```